# Redirect an user based on group in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to redirect a user to a view  after authentication based on the user's group.

I have been thinking something like this.

```
if user is user.group = ServiceProvider 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin/')
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading about this I got the answer and is by the mean of a filter.

```
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    if user.groups.filter (name='Customers'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedincustomer/')
    elif user.groups.filter (name='Service Providers'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid/')
```